# Backbone.js global error handling

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am writing website with usage of Backbone.js for web front end and own RESTful server for API back end. My API (RESTful) server requires manual authorization and expects security token in "Authorization" header. If security token is deprecated or broken, API server will return response with 401 status code. I override Backbone.sync to send additional headers with requests and returning `options.error(jqXHR.status)` on AJAX error.

How can I add global error events listener to handle `options.error(...)` events on failed resources loading? I need it to make navigation redirect to `/#!/signin` page on `401 Unauthorized` response.

Comment: i would just like to ask how to add the additional headers? i'm doing the same thing. my server needs manual authorization.

Comment: Override `Backbone.sync` https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1289 , where create $.ajax request with custom header settings http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Global error handler for backbone.js ajax requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150514/global-error-handler-for-backbone-js-ajax-requests)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you could try to use the jQuery Global Ajax Event Handler:

http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/

You simply bind the `.ajaxError` event to the body or your application element and filter 401 status codes.

On a 401 error you redirect your application like `window.yourAppRouter.navigate(...)`

Comment: Actually this is only way I see. But I thought there is another better/proper way to do it.

Comment: the problem is your sync class doesn't know about your application and its router. The sync class can not redirect the user directly. Another approach could be to override the Sync and add an error handler for 401. If a 401 error occurs it triggers a custom event like 'sync:denied' and your application catches this event and redirects the user to signin.

Comment: @sled - How can you see what the error response code is in the Sync function? I can't seem to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

In a similar vein to the suggestion of Global Ajax Event Handler, you can handle this via the jQuery ajaxSetup method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19981363/886153