# backbone handle sessions expiring

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I was wondering if there was a standard way for backbone models/controllers to handle sessions ending. I am using node.js as the backend for my webapp, and for now am storing sessions in memory. This means that if the server is restarted session information will be lost. If the session information is lost then a call to the server to save a model might fail due to not having a user. If this happens, I'd like to pop up a login prompt or something. Is there a standard way to catch sessions ending from within a backbone model?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your server should respond with a concrete *error code* like [401](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error) and in the client layer respond to this kind of *error code* in a common behavior: like showing the login page you said.

You can capture this *error code* at a [jQuery level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150514/global-error-handler-for-backbone-js-ajax-requests).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `push-stream` pattern or `websocket` to keep the communication between your client and server. So if the server stop the communication the session has gone.

Other wise, you can define the time from last interaction with the server, and calculate the time to expire in the client by getting the date from last get/post that returned successfully.