# What's the best design/architecture practice to manage authentication (session) & authorization in a backbone.js application

Tags: authentication, backbone.js, authorization

I couldn't find much on this anywhere. Most of the sample applications just do not talk about security etc. Assume that user will be authenticated using a rest based API call. How the application should be structured to take care of authentication [Also authorization]. A pointer to sample application would be great. Please add views in terms of single page application as well as normal application.
[I believe each view should take care of it]

Comment: Sample applications don't talk about security because there's little (if anything) Backbone-specific to talk about.

Comment: Just so that I am more clear, I am interested in authentication/authorization patterns to be applied without compromising security. e.g. should I use a mediator pattern to save session/authorization information and each view should check this info before rendering. Or should this be taken care of by some other means

Comment: I figured it out. Best way is to create a parent route & view called authenticated route/view and derived all the routes/views, which require the user to be logged in from it. adding security on routes will not instantiate views unnecessary. Session security, authorization parameters etc need to be fetched from server and each request should be validated on server side as well for added security. Also see answer from Anthony to handle global errors etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Encountered the same problem a few months back doing a single-page app that consumes a REST based api. What I came up with after searching for answers was to use HTTP's existing 401 and 403 error. I had my api return these errors. Then caught the exceptions by using an extended error handling model to handle these errors and just routed them to my login via the router [navigate](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-navigate) function.

```
var ErrorHandlerModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

    initialize: function(attributes, options) {
        options || (options = {});
        this.on("error", this.errorHandler);
        this.init && this.init(attributes, options);
    },

    errorHandler: function(model, error) {
        if (error.status == 401 || error.status == 403) {
          app.history.navigate('login', true);
        }
    }

});
```

In hindsight though i think it would have been better to just use a global jquery [ajaxError](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/) function instead. Snippet above was based on a similar [question posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150514/global-error-handler-for-backbone-js-ajax-requests) a few months back.

I also had to override backbones default fetch behavior so i could trigger an error with the ogin to catch a response variable included in the json response of the api.

```
var Login = Backbone.Model.extend({  

    urlRoot: '/login',

    parse: function(resp,xhr) {
        if (resp.response == 'success') {
            app.history.navigate('dashboard', true);
        }
        else {
            this.trigger('loginError');     
        }
    return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: This sounds good. Where did you guys put in authentication check..was it in views or in controller e.g. lets say user lands on a dashboard after login now do you put in authentication code in controller instantiation or in view. I believe it makes sense to put in authorization check in views. Let me know if I am not clear enough.

Comment: If by controller you mean the router, yes we're doing auth check on the router, as we have user roles. At the same time we're also doing  auth check on views, for the same reason that we had to limit some events to certain user roles. For the actual user data we're actually using the Login model to store it and check this for the auth status. Just pasted a simplified version here.

Comment: cool. Thanks a lot. Before closing it would you mind sharing some sample code.

Comment: If you were going to use the ajaxError handler, would you put in logic inside that global handler for specific routes? Or is there a better way. I'm thinking about auth issues returning 401s when you want to display specific messages about why they failed, rather than a generic auth error.

Answer (score 8):

You're absolutely correct that most samples don't address security at all. And as a result I don't have a great sample that I can point you to. I can only tell you how we structured our own stuff:

1. Like you suggested, we make an API call to authenticate the user. In
   our case there was a session ID created by the Java server as soon
   as the user hit the first page (even prior to logging in) and stored
   in a cookie client side. Since that cookie travels up with every
   HTTPS request to the server (even the AJAX calls to get data or
   perform commands) it is associated with a particular account server
   side once the user has authenticated.
2. Assuming that your transport to the server is HTTPS and the cookie
   never travels over the open Internet, nobody can eavesdrop on that
   value and pretend to be that logged in user.
3. In our case the server is Java based and a servlet filter sits in front of all
   of the API functions which are not publicly accessible (that is, the
   ones that require login). It checks the session and makes sure it
   represents a logged in user before passing on the request to the service 
   and that keeps the service code clean of authentication
   checks. Authorization code and parameter validation however does currently 
   sit in the service layer.
4. AJAX calls to the API could fail to authenticate even when you do
   have a cookie accompanying them for a variety of reasons (the
   session has expired, the server had to be restarted and has
   forgotten the user's session, the admin forceably logged out the
   user, etc.). In our opinion, it's important that the server still
   return something (that is, not a empty response) and it shouldn't be 
   something like a redirect to a 
   login page (which is useless to an AJAX request). So we always
   return [JSend protocol](http://labs.omniti.com/labs/jsend) responses from all of our functions and if the
   user isn't logged in, then the servlet filter returns a standard JSend "error"
   response with a particular code. That allowed us to have our client side code 
   (which you could put 
   into a custom Sync) notice that the user isn't logged in and prompt for a login. It's
   even possible you could automatically retry the function after they login but that's
   more sophisticated than we got.
5. By having the Sync notice that the user isn't logged in or got a security violation
   you don't have to put anything special into the views. They just make whatever request
   they think is appropriate and it either succeeds or it doesn't. If a fresh login is
   needed, that gets triggered at a lower level.
6. Logging out does not actually require you to kill the local cookie
   as long as the server marks that given session as no longer logged
   in or discards the session record.

I disagree somewhat with Derick's statement that the client shouldn't know about security. I think it needs to know when to prompt for login, how to tell the server when to execute a logout, and I always think it's a good idea to have additional checks client side to avoid the principle of surprise. For example, I would prefer that the client suppress showing admin functions to me if I can't use them rather than allow me to try to invoke them and then get an error in response.

Ultimately the server absolutely must check the user's permissions again with each request (because it's so easy to sidestep client-side security), but good UX requires that the client know that I'm not an admin so it can present the best representation of the UI for me.

Comment: Thanks John it makes sense. Just see my comment to Derick's reply and let me know what your thoughts are.

Comment: This is an awesome answer. I've been thinking about these very issues. Thanks @John. Hey, why is it important to force the logout on the server instead of just nuking the local cookie or session? I can't think of an advantage there.

Comment: @SimpleAsCouldBe I don't think we thought it was important to force server logout, it's just how our logout worked. We triggered it and the server knew we were logged out. Then any further attempts to do anything client side were guaranteed to get failure responses and prompt for fresh logins. I'm not sure if, once you've deleted a client side cookie, if there's anything someone else with access to the machine or browser could do to restore it and gain access to the session server side.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Mu's comment. There's very little to talk about in terms of authentication.

How do you handle authentication with standard HTML apps that post back to your server? Do it that way because that's how it should be done.

For authorization, there is a little more to talk about, but not much. Essentially, you only send the user what they are allowed to see. You don't do authorization or authentication code in the browser, unless it's absolutely required. And it's never absolutely required in my experience.

JavaScript in a browser is not secure, so don't do things that rely on authentication and authorization in the browser.

I wrote a small article about some of this, here: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/01/26/modularity-and-security-in-composite-javascript-apps/

Comment: I agree with you partially i.e we should not rely on javascript completely but my question is more specific to backbone.js powered app, specially single page apps where views, models etc are on the client side. Now once I have got the token that user is authenticated (& authorized) how should I use that token..should I check the token in views and then accordingly render. Also Is it secured enough?

Comment: You're pretty secured at that point. Whether you're using a token you're sending with each request or a cookie like we used, you're basically just using the token as a proxy for the user's credentials and depending upon the server side to use that proxy to look up permissions to check. Something (whatever that something is) needs to go with each request, but that's it. We downloaded a set of additional information client side that included permission flags that could then be used when rendering to suppress or reveal interface elements, but that's not required.

Comment: @Derick Bailey, I down voted your answer for the sole reason that I see no answer in what have been asked.