# Parse.com/Backbone Global Error Handler

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, parse-platform

I have a 2-part question.

1. How can I *globally* handle errors in Parse (Backbone)
2. Such that whenever a connection error occurs, an alert is shown and the **request is resent** after the alert is hidden.

Part 1 is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150514/global-error-handler-for-backbone-js-ajax-requests). My confusion is in resending the request when the global error handler expressed in that answer doesn't point to the location of the original request, as well as the success and error callbacks it defines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery offers a very convenient way,

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(event, request, settings) {
    setTimeout( function(){
       $.ajax(settings);
    }, 2000)
});
```

The key part is the `settings` parameter which contains the original settings passed to  `$.ajax` which you can pass again to a new `ajax` request