# Check for 404 from Model Fetch in Backbone

Tags: backbone.js

I have this code:

```
var quote = new kf.Models.Quote();
quote.id = id;
quote.fetch();
```

Now, what I'm trying to do is work out how to catch a 404 from the REST API, if the specified quote does not exist on the server,

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Backbone documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch), you can pass in an options object to `fetch`, and define an `error` callback:

```
var quote = new kf.Models.Quote();
quote.id = id;
quote.fetch({
  error: function(model, xhr, options) {
    console.log("something went wrong!");
  }
});
```

Should do the job. You can also define a `success` callback if you have code that only needs to run if the Ajax call was successful.

[This other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150514/global-error-handler-for-backbone-js-ajax-requests) defines a number of other ways you can do it, including defining one function that is called for every Ajax error. Backbone also fires `"error"` events when something goes wrong, so you can bind to that when initialising your model:

```
this.bind("error", someFunc);
```